# Multiple Selectors + Nested Rule

Tags: css, less

I have some less like below:

```
    .char2, .char3, .char5, .char6{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;

        &:hover{
        .text-shadow(@blueDark, 2px, 2px, 20px);
        bottom:0.1em;
        .transform(rotate(30deg));
        }

        .char6:hover{
        .transform(rotate(-30deg));
        }
    }
```

So what I meant to do is to style char2-char6 hover state but specifically for char6, i want the hover to have some small extra styles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just move the `.char6:hover` rule outside the `{..}`. Just place it below the other rules.

Comment: thanks. thought lessjs has some shortcut syntax to do that.

Comment: My suggestion is just as many bytes, so no need for a shortcut syntax :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `.char6:hover` code outside of your `.char2, .char3, .char5, .char6` code block and remove the preceeding dot from the transform method:

```
.char2, .char3, .char5, .char6{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;

        &:hover{
        .text-shadow(@blueDark, 2px, 2px, 20px);
        bottom:0.1em;
        transform(rotate(30deg));
        }
    }

.char6:hover{
 transform(rotate(-30deg));
        }
```

I'm not familiar with the `&:hover` nested syntax so I'm taking your word for it that it's valid until I've had chance to research.

Comment: that is lessjs syntax. and yep, that's all I have to do.

Comment: Glad to have helped Henson. Remember to hit the Accept button :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove the char6:hover out of the char2-char6 definition:

```
.char2, .char3, .char5, .char6{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;

        &:hover{
        .text-shadow(@blueDark, 2px, 2px, 20px);
        bottom:0.1em;
        .transform(rotate(30deg));
        }
    }

.char6:hover{
        .transform(rotate(-30deg));
        }
```

Comment: This is correct. The original syntax translates to:

.char6 .char6:hover {...}

Answer (score 1):

Found an elegant solution:

```
    .char2, .char3, .char5, .char6{
       display:inline-block;
       position:relative;

    &:hover{
       .text-shadow(@blueDark, 2px, 2px, 20px);
       bottom:0.1em;
       .transform(rotate(30deg));
    }

    &.char6:hover{
       .transform(rotate(-30deg));
    }
}
```

My own example here: http://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/sdApx